# PyTorch distributed dataLoader

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, distributed, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

Any recommended ways to make PyTorch DataLoader (`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`) work in distributed environment, single machine and multiple machines? Can it be done without `DistributedDataParallel`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to make your question clear. `DistributedDataParallel` is abbreviated as `DDP`, you need to train a model with `DDP` in a distributed environment. This question seems to ask how to arrange the dataset loading process for distributed training.

First of all,

`data.Dataloader` is proper for both dist and non-dist training, usually, there is no need to do something on that.

But the sampling strategy varies in this two modes, you need to specify a sampler for the dataloader(the `sampler` arg in `data.Dataloader`), adopting  `torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler`  is the simplest way.